# How to show specific page links on Google search results page?

Tags: google-search

How can show specific page in mentioned area when any one search my brand name on Google? See the example below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this website:

https://contextneutral.com/story/how-to-add-ldjson-structured-data-to-your-angularjs-app

```
/*  visit www.apple.com and look at
    the source code to find it.
*/
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@id": "https://www.apple.com/#organization",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Apple",
        "url": "https://www.apple.com/",
        "logo": "https://www.apple.com/ac/structured-datahttps://cdn.contextneutral.com/i/knowledge_graph_logo.png?201703170823",
        "contactPoint": [
            {
                "@type": "ContactPoint",
                "telephone": "+1-800-692-7753",
                "contactType": "sales",
                "areaServed": [ "US" ]
            }
        ],
        "sameAs": [
            "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q312",
            "https://www.youtube.com/user/Apple",
            "https://www.linkedin.com/company/apple",
            "https://www.facebook.com/Apple",
            "https://www.twitter.com/Apple"
        ]
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hello i hope you doing great we are using next.js to do all those I not sure how is this going to help in google sub page result ? I searched a did not get any relevent info on the above question